# Get Woocommerce currency symbol from order in YITH invoice plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency, orders

Our WooCommerce site has 2 currencies. The primary currency is the Indian **rupee** and the secondary currency is **USD** (using currency switcher). I tried placing an order in USD but the YITH invoice shows the primary Indian rupee symbol in the invoice.

I have tried changing to all sorts of currency switcher plugins available but the symbol won't change in the invoice, it simply takes the default currency symbol.

I even tried adding 'get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()' to currency arg array to the YITH function. I Need help. The plugin used is YITH Invoice ver: 1.3.11.

```
function yith_get_formatted_price ( $price, $args = array () ) {
    extract ( apply_filters ( 'wc_price_args', wp_parse_args ( $args, array (
        'ex_tax_label'       => false,
        'currency'           => get_woocommerce_currency_symbol (),
        'decimal_separator'  => wc_get_price_decimal_separator (),
        'thousand_separator' => wc_get_price_thousand_separator (),
        'decimals'           => wc_get_price_decimals (),
        'price_format'       => get_woocommerce_price_format (),
    ) ) ) );

    $negative = $price < 0;
    $price    = apply_filters ( 'raw_woocommerce_price', floatval ( $negative ? $price * - 1 : $price ) );
    $price    = apply_filters ( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', number_format ( $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ), $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );

    if ( apply_filters ( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', false ) && $decimals > 0 ) {
        $price = wc_trim_zeros ( $price );
    }

    $formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf ( $price_format, get_woocommerce_currency_symbol ( $currency ), $price );
    $return          = $formatted_price;

    return apply_filters ( 'wc_price', $return, $price, $args );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The only way to get the order currency symbol** (or code) is first getting the **`WC_Order`** object and you can get it from the `global $order;` object or from the `$order_id` with:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

Now you can use on it the **`WC_Abstract_Order`** method **`get_currency()`** to get the currency code and finally you will get the currency symbol this way:

```
$currency_code = $order->get_currency();
$currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency_code );
```

This is tested and works on WooCommerce 3+

Comment: Yes that worked perfect. Since $current_order = $document->order; was already defined in the invoice function page. I then had to add a method //global $woocommerce; $order_currency = $current_order->get_order_currency(); followed by array( 'currency' => $order_currency) wherever wc_price was used to get prices.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```php
"currency"=>get_woocommerce_currency()
```