# Get the symbol and code of the order currency for a custom meta field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code that shows the value of a custom field in a php template invoice, where I also show the code of the order currency, but the currency symbol does not appear, I am using part of the code from the answer @LoicTheAztec of the question, to show the code and symbol of the order currency [Get Woocommerce currency symbol from order in YITH invoice plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606942/get-woocommerce-currency-symbol-from-order-in-yith-invoice-plugin)

[image]

```
    <?php
        $custom_order_meta = get_post_meta($order->get_order_number(), 'costoseguro', true);
    
        if( ! empty($custom_order_meta) )
        { ?>
    <p> <?php
    printf( '<b>Insured Package Value:</b> ' . esc_html( '%s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html($custom_order_meta)  );?> <?php $currency_code = $order->get_currency();
$currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency_code ); ?></p> <?php 
        }
        ?>
```

in the fuctions.php file I use this code to change currency symbol and code: `

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_currency_symbol', 10, 2 );
function change_currency_symbol( $symbols, $currency ) {
    if ( 'USD' === $currency ) {
        return 'USD $ ';
    }
    if ( 'EUR' === $currency ) {
        return 'EUR € ';
    }
    if ( 'COP' === $currency ) {
        return 'COP $';
    }
        return $symbols;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_currency()` function and `get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()` function will not output anything. They simply retrieve a value, so you will have to incorporate them in your `printf()` function if you want to show them. Also I think a `switch` statement is better suited for your filter. So your code would look something like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_currency_symbol', 10, 2 );
function change_currency_symbol( $symbol, $currency ) {
    switch ( $currency ) {
        case 'USD':
            $symbol = 'USD $';
            break;
        case 'EUR':
            $symbol = 'EUR €';
            break;
        case 'COP':
            $symbol = 'COP $';
            break;
    }
    return $symbol;
}
```

```
if ( !empty( $order->get_meta( 'costoseguro' ) ) ) {
    printf( '<p><b>Insured Package Value:</b> %s %s</p>', $order->get_meta( 'costoseguro'), get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $order->get_currency() ) );
}
```

(Also note calling `get_post_meta()` to retrieve order meta is quite outdated. You can better use `$order->get_meta()` for this.)